# libapache2-mod-mono won't configure during apt-get install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, installation, mod-mono

Good morning Experts!

I'm trying to install libapache2-mod-mono on Ubuntu 14.04:

> sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono

but i get the following error:

> Setting up libapache2-mod-mono (3.8-0xamarin2+compat1) ... Using
>   mono-apache-server4... dpkg: error processing package
>   libapache2-mod-mono (--configure):  subprocess installed
>   post-installation script returned error exit status 1 Errors were
>   encountered while processing:  libapache2-mod-mono E: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

i've ran 
sudo apt-get install -f
and
sudo dpkg --configure -a
to no avail.

The .postinst file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

# Set up the environment
set -e

. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule db_version 2.0 

# Automatically added by dh_apache2
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] && test -n ; then
   if [ -e /usr/share/apache2/apache2-maintscript-helper ] ; then
      . /usr/share/apache2/apache2-maintscript-helper
      apache2_invoke enmod mod_mono_auto.load mod_mono.load  || exit #ERROR_HANDLER#
   fi  
fi
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_makeshlibs
if [ "$1" = "configure" ]; then
   ldconfig
fi
# End automatically added section
```

Is there anything here that look wrong or incorrect? I'm only a beginner to linux and bash, and nothing immediately jumps out at me. Alternatively, is there some other reason why I can't seem to configure libapache2-mod-mono in order to complete the install.

Regards,

Donovan

Comment: ok, it looks like I get the following error in line 6:
db_version: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I just had to delete the file `/var/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-mono.postinst` and reinstall the package via apt-get

Comment: /var/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-mono.postinst